# phpmyadmin not allowing to create database despite changing $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] to config from cookie

Tags: phpmyadmin

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5jBQ.png)

Some more information about my localhost server:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: phpmyadmin@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)


 Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

Although i tried reinstalling and even change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

Comment: are you logged in as root?

Comment: @suppko Yes I logged in as root only

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, you are not logged in as root:

**User: phpmyadmin@localhost**

So this user phpmyadmin@localhost does not have the privilege to create a database.

Comment: When I was installing phpmyadmin it asked for a password. But that password is not working for username: root whereas it is working for username:phpmyadmin. So i guess phpmyadmin is alias for root user

Comment: I haven't set up any password for root but still its not allowing me to login via username:root

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing as user account alias in MySQL. Here is how you can reset the root password: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html